# How to analyze ordered data type with past missing observations?

Tags: regression, missing-data, ordered-logit, generalized-estimating-equations

I am having trouble understanding what method to apply for the analysis of the following type of data:

```
id  period  grade   GLP NAB ROE ROA OSS ESS PMA P30
1   1   NA  1790835 769 0.3795033   0.1171393   1.66014 1.221868    0.3976413   0.007312334
1   2   NA  2597351 1143    0.5896583   0.188034    1.947474    1.748581    0.4865142   0.01906484
1   3   15  3359203 1343    0.474556    0.1559151   1.814949    1.712795    0.4490202   0.02821528
2   3   16  12271110    15960   0.05    0.01    1.04    1.04    0.04    0.02
2   1   NA  5392109 9290    -0.02   -0.01   0.96    0.7 -0.04   0.02
2   2   NA  11128069    1253    -0.03332067 -0.005665337    0.9908606   0.9871047   -0.00922374 0.01818852
3   2   NA  820903  2225    0.06835087  0.004860066 1.012239    0.9919102   0.01209093  0.072
...
9   2   NA  652028  364 0.027   0.007   1.027   0.982   0.026   0.008
10  2   NA  31731236    251352  0.07033455  0.01930156  1.11506 1.069495    0.1031871   0.01566419
10  3   20  33016098    247747  0.0750367   0.02032998  1.124112    1.086046    0.1104093   0.01443777
10  1   NA  25151189    217818  0.03529102  0.01133722  1.059813    1.052836    0.0564377   0.02853068
```

They refer to credit ratings computed over three periods. The dependent variable is the grade (therefore ordered) and it does also depend on periods 1 and 2, but it not assigned until period 3, and therefore is missing. I thought to use ordered GEEs with a logit link, but in that case I would have either to put in the grade vector 0 or the period 3 values for each subject to analyze everything. Do you have any idea how to maintain the past observation without 'falsifying' the data? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting a statistics professor specialized in GLMs, I realized this is not a longitudinal set with respect to the ordered value (because grades are assigned only in period 3) but a cross-section with lags, so a proportional odds logistic regression will make it.